# Clipping vector layer to coastline

Tags: leaflet

I was wondering if there was a method to clip a vector layer to a coastline. ie. the layer is only visible over the sea, not the land or vice-versa. I'm guessing I need a layer which describes all coastlines and somehow use that as a mask?

Regards,
Tim.

Answer (score 0):

That would be pretty tough to do on the client-side, but I think it makes more sense to do server-side preprocessing of your data. Then you would serve already clipped vector layers to Leaflet.